# With apache installed on a mac system (MAMP) how can I enable the browser to access a file with special characters in the filename (like #)?

Tags: macos, apache, query-string, mamp, mamp-pro

On a linux filesystem this works fine but on Mac OS X Yosemite or El Capitain it doesn't.

The filename would be something like:
`/htdocs/app/webroot/files/#1234-file.jpg`

On linux you can access this in the browser with: `http://localhost/myapp/files/%231234-file.jpg`

... but this doesn't work on Mac OS X. Instead you get `Forbidden 403` with the error in the logs being: `Directory index forbidden by Options directive` (which is somewhat misleading because the URL is not asking for an index).

*UPDATE*
This is not a file permissions issue – I can access the file if I change it's name. Also not a browser issue: same behaviour in Safari, Chrome, Firefox.

Comment: chmod -R 777 /my/dir/path

Comment: @Pootie Tang No, I already tried that. Changing permissions makes no difference. I can access the file if I change it's name, removing the "#" character.

Comment: must be a browser issue.. surely you tried other browsers?

Comment: Same behaviour in Safari, Chrome, Firefox.

Comment: Urlencoded `%231234-file.jpg` form works fine on my El Capitan with native apache. Maybe you have mod_rewrite rule or some other config option set that breaks it.

Comment: But my filename is "#1234-file.jpg" not "%231234-file.jpg"... that's the point.

Comment: @geoidesic That is exactly what I tested: local file `#1234-file.jpg` and in the browser I put urlencoded `%231234-file.jpg`